# Java generic classes

Tags: java, class

I understand that in the fields of a class, you can make the field type the name of another class and then in the constructor initialise that field by calling a new class of that type, i.e.

```
public class Auction {
    private Bid bid;
}
public Auction {
    bid = new Bid();
}
```

The main reason for doing this is, as I understand it, to access the methods of that class.

My question is I've noticed in some methods that there are local variables created that have a type of a different class with a variable name. What is the purpose of assigning a local variable name with a type of another class? Is this another way of just accessing those methods directly, even if it hasn't been done in the fields or constructor?

Comment: What you ask is unclear, can you elaborate (with some pseudo code) on "what is the purpose of assigning a local variable name with a type of another class?"

Comment: This has nothing to do with generics, you're setting a field to have a value which is the type of *another* class. Java `String` is a common class (I presume) you're used to using as fields. It's like that.

Comment: Your code is invalid and I'm not 100% sure whether you're asking *"How to invoke instance methods without a instance?"* here.

Comment: Where in your question are there local variables?

Comment: so say in this method //close a bid public void close { Person p; Bid bid; for{Lots lot: lot} {.......The fact that both local variables p and bid have been given types that are of class Person and class bid, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this assignment only if type of the right part [is-a](http://learnwithharsha.com/my-first-java-lesson-is-a-and-has-a-relationships/) type of the left part. So, for example, you can use methods of left part' type with realization from right part' type.

```
Number number = new Integer(10);
```

See also [OOP in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/) and [Polymorphism in Java](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm).

Comment: Please use `Integer.valueOf()`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030817/differences-between-new-integer123-integer-valueof123-and-just-123

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to learn some basics about OOP. We use `Objects` to model the problems and solve them in Object Oriented Programming.

These *"type of a different class with a variable name"* is an instance of a class, which is called an **Object**. We can assign a variable name to an object in order to use that object and its behaviors.