# Java Wrapper class reference pointing to a primitive value

Tags: java, wrapper, boxing

I have a doubt in Java wrapper class like `Integer`, `Character`. I know that when we declare a class `Abc` and can create an object to it in Java like

```
Abc a = new Abc();
```

It instantiates a with reference to `Abc` class and in that we have fields that contain values for variables. My doubt being, when we create `Integer` class like:

```
Integer i = 5;
```

How is it pointing to value `5`? Should not it contain a field which contains its value and point to `Integer` object like:

```
static int value; // To hold value 5 for Integer class
```

Comment: we cannot declare class like **Abc a = new Abc();**, in Java. You are creating an object

Comment: This is called autoboxing, when you write `Integer i = 5;` your compiler at compile time change it to `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(5);`

Comment: Although this question requires just a brief research, downvoting is not a way to encourage new users. Why don't you leave a comment?

Comment: Sorry @Andrew I got my mistake. This can be a useful link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030817/differences-between-new-integer123-integer-valueof123-and-just-123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is it pointing to value 5?

It's pointing to an `Integer` instance which holds that primitive value.

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(5);
```

which is a bit optimised version of `new Integer(5)` (this one is deprecated since Java 9). The process is called [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) and is made by the compiler.

> Should not it contain a field which contains its value?

It does contain a field. Though, it shouldn't be static and shared for the whole class.

```
private final int value;
```

Actually, `Integer.valueOf(5)` will be taken from the cache as well as any value in the range `[-128, 127]` unless a greater `java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high` value is specified.

Comment: Sir, Are not final variables supposed to be initialized in constructors or non-static initializers only?

Comment: @Handmadegiftsco, yes, they are. But a static method could call a constructor or refer to another static member (have a look at `static final Integer cache[]` inside `private static class IntegerCache`)

Answer (score 1):

To quote [the Javadoc for Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)

> An object of type Integer contains a single field whose type is int.

So yes, there is a field of type `int` in the object returned by the autoboxing.  The `Integer` object returned by autoboxing might be

- newly created, or
- returned from a cache;

but it will be the same as the object returned by the static `valueOf` method of the `Integer` class.

The [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20877086) may help you understand when `valueOf` (and therefore autoboxing) creates a new object, and when it returns an existing object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer i = 5;
```

from this, the compiler will make `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(5);`(Autoboxing)

See also Oracle Docs in

[Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

[The Numbers Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html)

[Immutable Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html)

Comment: Sir how can a reference variable for class like i in this case point to value?

Comment: You can't pass a wrapper class by reference. Because are immutable, for that, you will need return the value from your method.