# Boxing and unboxing equality java

Tags: wrapper, equals, boxing, unboxing

```
    Integer a = new Integer(3);
    Integer b = 3;

        System.out.println(a==b);
        System.out.println(a.equals(b));
```

> **output**:
>   false
>   true

can someone explain why this example is valid?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030817/differences-between-new-integer123-integer-valueof123-and-just-123

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly compare two Integers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/how-to-properly-compare-two-integers-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

The **==** operator compares the equality of the *objects*. Since both objects have their own id/location in the heap memory, this check evaluates to false.

The .equals() method compares the *actual values* of both objects, in this case 3, which is true.